# Shader displaying wrong color; blur effect in Shading workspace

Tags: modeling, shaders, blur, workspaces

Blender was running fine but in my wisdown I decided to uninstall it to reset everything to defaults. After reinstalling, the shader base color I chose was displaying incorrectly. I chose red and the shader appeared deep pink in Rendered view. Only the lighting works.

In Shading workspace, other problems occur. Using the Pan, Zoom and Transform tools cause a blur effect on the object so that it is hard to see where the actual object is. The "old" object highlighted outline (orange) remains while the newly calculated object view is dark gray. I have tried many fixes to no avail:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled three times.
2. Used a prog like CC Cleaner to target and remove files.
3. Manually removed files and folders throughout the C: drive (as many as I could find, even hidden AppData)
4. Tried running Blender through Steam.
5. Used a restore point recovery, going back five days.
6. Deleted one Blender key in the Windows uninstall folder in the registry.

Thank you.

[image: Base Color is red]

[image: Object shown as deep pink in Rendered view of Modeling workspace]

[image: Blur effect in Shading workspace. Orange highlight is original object location. Zooming out, highlight remains.]

Comment: Please edit your question and make the images visible as part of the question, instead of havin users click on many links.

Comment: This seems like a bug with the Principle shader.  Try playing around with going into the Shading tab and deleting the Principle shader, adding a diffuse shader, rendering, unchecking "Use Nodes" in the Worlds tab of the Properties editor (and maybe in the Material settings), and then replacing the diffuse shader with the Principle shader.  Doing combinations of that sometimes worked for me, though not consistently.  Creating the materials in the shading tab rather than the layout tab worked for me once, but not the second time.

Comment: I'll check if it's fixed in 2.90α. In the meantime, just avoid the Principle shader

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "deleting Principle shader." Do you mean the Principled BSDF? And if so, I am to change to Diffuse BSDF? I really think something is just wrong w/my computer. It doesn't make sense. Somehow, despite uninstalling and reinstalling Blender 2.8, no matter whether I use the standard version, Steam, or the portable version, the same thing keeps happening. The program opens fine, shows the standard cube. I can move it, rotate, etc., but Shading causes problems. Then the blur effect starts. Every single time. No amount of deleting files or registry keys has worked.